# Como hacer que cambie de color una div cuando un enlace tenga el foco (con html y css)

Tags: focus

Como puedo hacer para que cuando un enlace (eje: enlace-1) tenga el foco, una div (eje: contenido-1) cambie de color y los demas enlaces y divs bajen su opacidad en el siguiente código HTML:

"

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="enlace-1">Enlace 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="enlace-2">Enlace 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="enlace-3">Enlace 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="enlace-4">Enlace 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="enlace-5">Enlace 5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


      <div class="container-items">
        <div class="contenido-1">Contenido 1</div>
        <div class="contenido-2">Contenido 2</div>
        <div class="contenido-3">Contenido 3</div>
        <div class="contenido-4">Contenido 4</div>
        <div class="contenido-5">Contenido 5</div>
      </div>
```

"

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con CSS y JavaScript de esta forma:
Ajusto primero tu código HTML

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll("nav ul li a");
  const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".container-items div");

  links.forEach((link, index) => {
    link.addEventListener("focus", function() {
      contents.forEach(content => {
        content.classList.remove("active");
      });
      contents[index].classList.add("active");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container-items div {
  display: none;
}

.container-items div.active {
  display: block;
}

.container-items div {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.container-items div:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="enlace-1">Enlace 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="enlace-2">Enlace 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="enlace-3">Enlace 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="enlace-4">Enlace 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="enlace-5">Enlace 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-items">
  <div class="contenido-1">Contenido 1</div>
  <div class="contenido-2">Contenido 2</div>
  <div class="contenido-3">Contenido 3</div>
  <div class="contenido-4">Contenido 4</div>
  <div class="contenido-5">Contenido 5</div>
</div>
```

Recuerda acomodar respectivamente cada código, ya sea en archivos individuales o con las etiquetas de html  y